# outlook 365 groups view inboxes through pop3

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, imap, office365, pop3

My work uses outlook 365, I prefer gmail so I have opened my work email in gmail by setting up the pop3 and imap settings.

However I have run into a problem with outlook 365 groups, in that these emails are not being sent on the pop3, I think because these are different accounts and I am "following" them rather than actually having the emails. This mean I can see emails to these groups in my outlook inbox but not my gmail inbox.

How do I set it up so I get these emails in my gmail?

Comment: Why POP3 _and_ IMAP? You really shouldn't be using POP3 - welcome to the 21st Century.. Also, do you really mean O365 Groups or have you moved to Teams?

Comment: It is this stuff https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Outlook-Blog/Introducing-Follow-in-inbox-and-other-improvements-for-managing/ba-p/102611
What in the alternative to pop3/imap for this?

Comment: Don't use POP3: it was obsoleted years ago by IMAP.

Comment: I'm not quite understand this: "My work uses outlook 365, I prefer gmail so I have opened my work email in gmail by setting up the pop3 and imap settings." May I know how did you achieve this?

Comment: see https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-access-free-windows-live-hotmail-in-gmail-1172110